# Not finding wfs geoserver url

Tags: geoserver, wms

I need some help. I am new to the concept of Geoserver and WFS and I am looking for very basic help. I have downloaded and installed Geoserver, now I need to get WFS url to work in openlayers3. When I tried using WMS…Im able to get layers overlayed in ol3,but I am not sure how to get the URL for WFS in geoserver.Any help or pointing in the right direction of information would be most appreciated. Thanks,
Sasi.

Answer (score 1):

Your WFS url is very like the WMS url - just change the service name and version

```
http://example.com/geoserver/wfs?
  service=wfs&
  version=1.1.0&
  request=GetCapabilities
```